# How to define which field a treestore should display as node text with ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, treepanel

In my ExtJS 4 app, I have a Model (with one field "name"), a Treestore and a Treepanel. I want the Treepanel to display the "name" field of my model. How can it be specified ? 
Default Nodes have a "text" field, which is displayed on the tree. But isn't it possible to tell the Tree to display someting else from the Model ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `displayField` config:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-cfg-displayField